# GCM server on a local computer?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Would it be possible to use GCM to have an app installed on a persons computer send messages to an Android phone? Or does GCM require to be on a server - for example maybe it requires one GCM server ID per service or somesuch?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible (as long as you don't restrict your API key to work on a specific whitelisted IP). I tested sending GCM messages from my computer to my device and it works without any problem. Any application that can send HTTP requests to GCM server can send messages to devices.

The part that might be a problem is for the Android device to send its registration ID to the computer where the sender app is intalled. I'm not sure how would that be achieved with a sender app that's not deployed on a server.